# Разбить текст на абзацы python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Нужно разбить текст по абзацам в python.
Не получается разбить текст именно по абзацам, а не по предложениям или строкам. Понятно что  в абзаце может быть разное кол-во символов и предложений. Каждый абзац начинается с пропуска строки от предыдущего

Вот пример текста:

Пример абзаца

Пример абзаца

Пример абзаца

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если абзац - это два переноса строки, то элементарно.

```
s = 'Мой какой-то текст. ЭТо первый абзац.\n\nТут начинается второй абзац. И в нём два предложения.\n\n А это - третий, и он стосит из одного предложения.'
paragraphs = s.split('\n\n')
```

в paragraphs будет список абзацев.

Answer (score 1):

Считайте все строки с помощью `readlines()`.

Пройдитесь по элементам полученного списка. Если встретится элемент `'\n'` (пустая строка) -- добавляйте все последующие строки в очередной "абзац" (как он у Вас будет храниться -- решать Вам).

Кроме того, первые строки до первого вхождения `'\n'` также добавьте в "абзац".

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!